# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath' in react native

Tags: reactjs, native

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'test1'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.4.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.4.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.4/gradle-4.4.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.4/gradle-4.4.pom'.
  >   Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/75.126.118.188] failed: Connection timed out: connect
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23s
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Please state your RN version, how you're building the app and also your OS

Comment: react-native-cli: 2.0.1 and windows 10

Answer (score -1, accepted):

to solve 443 error must use VPN

Answer (score 0):

The resolution for me was to clear my gradle cache and rebuild.

For me on a mac, that meant clearing the `~/.gradle/caches` folder.

On windows it should be via `C:\Users\<user>\.gradle\caches`